# LLDB: error: attach failed: unable to find executable for '...'

Tags: clang, llvm, freebsd, lldb

I compiled `PostgreSQL` on `FreeBSD 10.2` using `CLang 3.7`. The problem is that I can't attach to the backend process using `LLDB 3.7`:

```
[eax@freebsd102 ~]$ ps wuax | grep postgres 
eax   29177   0.0  2.0 169592 20888  -  Is    6:11PM   0:00.00 postgres: checkpointer process    (postgres)
eax   29178   0.0  2.0 169592 20924  -  Ss    6:11PM   0:00.07 postgres: writer process    (postgres)
eax   29179   0.0  2.0 169592 20924  -  Ss    6:11PM   0:00.01 postgres: wal writer process    (postgres)
eax   29180   0.0  2.1 169592 21140  -  Is    6:11PM   0:00.01 postgres: autovacuum launcher process    (postgres)
eax   29181   0.0  1.0  24320 10216  -  Ss    6:11PM   0:00.00 postgres: stats collector process    (postgres)
eax   29192   0.0  2.3 169592 23456  -  Ss    6:14PM   0:00.04 postgres: eax eax [local] idle (postgres)
eax   29083   0.0  2.0 169592 20880  0  S     6:06PM   0:00.07 /usr/home/eax/postgresql-install/bin/postgres -D /home/eax/postgresql-install/data
eax   29196   0.0  0.2  18824  2340  1  S+    6:15PM   0:00.00 grep postgres
[eax@freebsd102 ~]$ lldb -p 29192
(lldb) process attach --pid 29192
error: attach failed: unable to find executable for 'postgres: eax eax [local] idle'
(lldb) q
```

In the same time everything works as expected for processes with "regular names":

```
[eax@freebsd102 ~]$ lldb -p 29192
(lldb) process attach --pid 29192
error: attach failed: unable to find executable for 'postgres: eax eax [local] idle'
(lldb) q
[eax@freebsd102 ~]$ lldb -p 29083
(lldb) process attach --pid 29083
Process 29083 stopped

Executable module set to "/usr/home/eax/postgresql-install/bin/postgres".
Architecture set to: x86_64-unknown-freebsd10.2-unknown.
(lldb) bt
* thread #1: tid = 100429, 0x000000080147beea libc.so.7`__sys_select + 10
  * frame #0: 0x000000080147beea libc.so.7`__sys_select + 10
    frame #1: 0x000000000081a326 postgres`ServerLoop + 262 at postmaster.c:1654
    frame #2: 0x0000000000817db8 postgres`PostmasterMain(argc=3, argv=0x00007fffffffeab0) + 6008 at postmaster.c:1298
    frame #3: 0x00000000007481a9 postgres`main(argc=3, argv=0x00007fffffffeab0) + 793 at main.c:228
    frame #4: 0x0000000000471baf postgres`_start + 367
(lldb) q
```

Any ideas how to solve this issue?

UPD: There is no such issue in gdb/gcc.

Comment: Have you also installed the postgresql client? http://www.freshports.org/databases/postgresql94-client/

Comment: Naturally. In fact this process I'm trying to connect to is responsible for handling client connection (on server side) I opened in the second terminal.

Comment: `-s` option is to specify a text file with `lldb` commands to execute, not the executable, isn't?

Comment: Right, this screenshot is a bit unsuccessful. I also tried -f argument, no arguments, etc - nothing solves a problem.

Comment: Did you try to start postgres-client from `lldb`, like it's described in the `Loading a program into lldb` section in this document? http://lldb.llvm.org/tutorial.html

Comment: Can you file a bug with the lldb.llvm.org bugzilla, somebody on the linux side will take a look.  It looks like postgres is changing the value of argv[0] before we attach, and we're using that to find the binary associated with executable.

Comment: Amiramix, I don't have a problem with postgresql client. I can't attach to the postgresql _server_. But for the record - yes, I can start psql under lldb.

Comment: Jim Ingham, sure, no problem https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=26924